# Access List values from another method is assigned in; C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have variable list `effectedCourseInstances` defined in controller and assigning value to it in `ProcessCourseApplicationURL()` method but after round trip from view, list don't hold value any more as it got `null`. I want to ensure that I can access to assigned values to `effectedCourseInstances` in `GetAllProcessedURLCourses()` method. Where I am doing wrong????

```
public class CourseManagementController : Controller
{
  private List<CourseInstanceModel> _effectedCourseInstances;

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult ProcessCourseApplicationURL(CourseApplicationsURLFeed_Model obj)
  {
    try
    {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        _effectedCourseInstances = _coursesServices.ProcessAllCoursesApplicationURL(obj);
      }
    }
    catch (DataException ex)
    {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable To Process Courses Application URL from CID DB" + ex);
    }
    return PartialView("CourseApplicationURLTest_Partial", _effectedCourseInstances);
  } //end

  public ActionResult GetAllProcessedURLCourses([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
  {
    DataSourceResult CourseInstances_Feed_Result = _effectedCourseInstances.ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(CourseInstances_Feed_Result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
}
```

Comment: In Web world, nothing is persisted unless you do with some techniques like sessions, cache,etc.

Comment: can I use global variable here ????

Comment: No. All variables, be it local or global, everything will be recycled once the request is processed. That's how the framework has been designed. You can go with 'Static' variables, but there are lot of things you need to consider (one is they are shared by all the sessions, if multiple users are accessing it). The HTTP Session and Cache objects are meant for this purpose, why do you need another approach?

Comment: I need to show list data to user to accept or decline before storing in database!

Comment: What do you do in ProcessAllCoursesApplicationURL() method? Does it depends on any of the parameter passed to it through input object? If Yes, consider not to use a stored version of it as another user could change its content.

Comment: `_effectedCourseInstances` is initialized each time a request is made so it will always be null. Its not really clear what your trying to do here